# T-SQL query in Databricks

Tags: t-sql, databricks

I am working with column of type string named `tl_deal_deal_cur_cal`. The column contains values such as

```
0
15
7.23
72.33
91.7
-25.1
-25.12
```

I need to transform these values into a new format as follows:

```
| Original | Transformed     |
|        0 | 000000000000000 |
|       15 | 000000000000015 |
|     7.23 | 000000000000723 |
|    72.33 | 000000000007233 |
|    91.7  | 000000000009170 | 
|   -25.1  | 000000000002510 | 
|   -25.12 | 000000000002512 |
```

The format must adhere to the following criteria:

- decimal points are removed, with the last two digits in the resulting string representing the original decimal portion. For example, `7.23` becomes `723`, `91.7` becomes `9170`, and `15` becomes `1500`.
- Negative values are converted to their absolute (positive) values.
- Zeros are prepended to the start of the string, such that the total string length is 15 characters.

I've attempted to write a T-SQL query in Databricks to accomplish this:

```
CASE
WHEN INSTR(tl_deal_deal_cur_cal, '.') > 0
   THEN RIGHT(CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(LEFT(tl_deal_deal_cur_cal, INSTR(tl_deal_deal_cur_cal, '.') - 1), '-', ''), 14, '0'), REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tl_deal_deal_cur_cal, INSTR(tl_deal_deal_cur_cal, '.') + 1, LEN(tl_deal_deal_cur_cal)), '.', '')), 15)
ELSE RIGHT(CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(tl_deal_deal_cur_cal, '-', ''), 14, '0'), '0'), 15)
END AS test7
```

However, I am encountering some issues. For instance, the value `15.4` results in `000000000000154` rather than the correct `000000000001540`. Negative values are being converted to a positive, but is not handling the the decimal places correctly. For example `-127.1` yields `000000000001271` instead of the correct `000000000012710`

Could someone help me out?

Comment: According to your description, `15.4` should be `'000000000001540'`, so why is that value the "incorect [sic] value"?

Comment: Yes you're right sorry my mistake I've made the correction thanks for the remark

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following t-sql, does this work for you?

```
select col, Concat(Replicate('0', 15 - Len(v)), v) NewCol
from t
cross apply(values(Replace(Cast(Abs(Try_Convert(Decimal(9,2), col)) as Varchar(10)), '.','')))v(v);
```

Output:

[image]